# Asynchronous invoke triggering aws lambda twice

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a chat application that when I click a button after typing in a message, the message gets posted to my DynamoDB table. The application is suppose to post the message once, but somehow is posting it twice.

The pipeline is as follows:

Client clicks `send` button --> hits my Google Cloud Endpoint API --> triggers my Google Cloud function --> invokes my AWS lambda function --> `POSTS` message DynamoDB.

With the help of SO, I've isolated the problem to my Google Cloud function invoking Lambda asynchronously which is queuing the Lambda twice.

> With async, requests are queued before actually executing. So, if you call it once, AWS will check if there's one executing already, if not, it will add another one.

[image] ([AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/))

Ideally I'd like to invoke my Lambda synchronously but according to this Github [post](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/885#issuecomment-260080124), I'd get billed twice (?). He mentions increasing the timeout of my function, but it's already set at 60 seconds - plenty of time for my lambda to send a response back. Is there some other mechanism that's queuing my lambda twice?

For your reference my Google cloud function is as follows:

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: ''
  secretAccessKey: ''
  region: ''
})

let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.helloWorld = async (req,res) =>{
  let payload = {
    pathParameters: req.query.p,
    httpMethod: req.method,
    body: req.method == "POST" ? req.body.message || req.body.user : null,
    cognitoUsername: req.query.u
  }

  let params = {
    FunctionName: '',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }

  res.status(200).send( await lambda.invoke(params, function(err,data){
    if (err){throw err}
    else {return data.Payload}
  }).promise())
}
```

**Solution**:

Based on @jarmod's solution, my Cloud function is shown below. The relevant part is at the end.

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: ''
  secretAccessKey: ''
  region: ''
})

let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.helloWorld = async (req,res) =>{
  let payload = {
    pathParameters: req.query.p,
    httpMethod: req.method,
    body: req.method == "POST" ? req.body.message || req.body.user : null,
    cognitoUsername: req.query.u
  }

  let params = {
    FunctionName: '',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }

  // code changed only here
  res.status(200).send( await lambda.invoke(params).promise())
}
```

**Edit**:

@Ngenator brought to my attention that my Google Cloud function may be getting triggered twice. For reference, this is my API yaml configuration:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
  version: 1.0.0
host: service.run.app
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: "service.run.app"
    allowCors: "true"
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /function-2:
    get:
      operationId: get 
      parameters:
        - name: p
          in: query
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: u
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://to.my/function-2
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
    post:
      operationId: post 
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: p
          in: query
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: u
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: body
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
              user:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://to.my/function-2
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

Comment: You may be mis-reading the GitHub issue. The point they're making is that if Lambda #1 invokes Lambda #2 synchronously then (obviously) Lambda #1 must wait around doing nothing while waiting for the (synchronous) response from Lambda #2. Hence they overlap in time, and in that sense you are 'paying twice'.

Comment: Look at the CloudWatch Logs for your Lambda function. Does it show that the Lambda completed normally, or that it failed (or timed out)? If you look at the logs for the two invocations that you think are duplicates, do they have the same request ID, or different?

Comment: Are you sure your google cloud function isn't actually triggering twice? Perhaps due to CORS and an OPTIONS request being handled as a post request?

Comment: @jarmod, went into my logs and indeed they're completing normally with two different request IDs.

Comment: @Ngenator, thank you for pointing that out! No, I don't know if it's Google function getting triggered twice. Please see my edited post for my API configuration for your reference. Will update you with my Cloud logs.

Comment: So you aren't writing any log messages for your own debugging or did you strip them out? If at this point you're confident everything up to here is only executing once, perhaps it's the dynamodb code

Comment: @Ngenator, I did write them at the bottom of this post. I'm fairly new to aws so please excuse my lack of knowledge. If there's more information from the log I can provide you, please let me know.

Comment: I meant debug print statements to sanity check your code. If my code isn't instrumented with something like datadog or newrelic (allowing me to see the distributed tracing as well as the call graph), the first thing I do when something doesn't behave as expected is insert a ton of print statements so I can see exactly what the code is doing

Comment: Your call to `lambda.invoke` is incorrect. It includes both a callback and awaits a promise. Use one or the other, preferably the latter: `await lambda.invoke(params).promise()`

Comment: @jarmod, this was the answer!!!

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an actual answer. I figured this was it, sorry I didn't actually read the code earlier but hopefully the journey was worth it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `lambda.invoke` is incorrect. It includes *both* a callback and awaits a promise. You should use one or the other, preferably the latter:

```
const rc = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
```